# container can't connect to MySQL server on 192.168.0.9

Tags: python, mysql, docker, sqlalchemy

I have a python function inside docker that uses sqlalchemy to connect to a MySQL database, and even tough this function works in my machine - and used to work inside airflow as well, it stopped working some days ago.

I even tried to run this function with python cli inside that container and got the same problem, with this log:

`sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '192.168.0.9' (timed out)")`

For reference, this is what my code looks like:

```
engineSql = sqlalchemy.create_engine('mysql+pymysql://...',connect_args={'connect_timeout': 10})
queryx='''SELECT DISTINCT  * FROM cdr limit 10'''
jp = pd.read_sql_query(queryx, engineSql)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this one to connect to your database:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, text

engine = create_engine("mysql+mysqlconnector://{username}:{password}@{hostname}:{port}/{database_name}")
mysql = engine.connect()

mysql.execute(text("create table test (id varchar(40) primary key , username varchar(255) , email varchar(255) , avatar varchar(255) )"))

mysql.close()
```

I think you didn't connect to your mysql engine. Hope it helps!